# Latest Facebook post

Tags: facebook, api, post

I'm trying to add a section of my site where my visitors can read all the latest posts from a company's twitter and facebook.

Twitter was really easy to implement, but now I am stuck at trying to find a solution to implement the latest facebook post.

I've looked on the facebook dev site as well searched on google, but most answers suggest fetching RSS feeds or other stuff that facebook no longer supports.

Does anyone know of how to do this? Is it even possible anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but maybe this will help someone.

I found this option:

Use the facebook page plugin.  Instructions are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin